# How to convert to asynchronous method with call back

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, threadpool

I have the following situation. I am using .net 4.5.1

I have a class called `ServiceRequest()`;

Request makes a connection using tcpclient to a server and gets data from it.

When you run `ServiceRequest.Start()` It starts a timer that then makes the request to the server every x minutes. ( I currently have no threading in the service class)

So the way I use it now:

```
private List<ServiceRequest> ServiceCommuncators = new List<ServiceRequest>();

//Load Services To monitor
serviceResp = new EFServiceRepository();
IList<Service> Services = GetAllServices();

//Setup Services
ItterateServices(Services);

//Start Service Requests
StartServiceRequests();

//Functions:
private void ItterateServices(IList<Service> services)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < services.Count; i++)
        {
            ServiceCommuncators.Add(new ServiceRequest(i, services[i].IpAddress, services[i].Port, services[i].PollInterval, ServicRequestCallBackFunction));
        }
    }

private void StartServiceRequests()
{
  foreach (ServiceRequest s in ServiceCommuncators)
  {
     s.Start();
  }
}

  public void ServicRequestCallBackFunction(ResponseObject response)
    {
        if (response.Successfull)
        {
            RecievedsuccessfulResponse(response);
        }
        else
        {
            // ServiceRequest Failed
            RecievedFailedResponse(response);
        }
    }
```

Now I want to make each request run asynchronously.

1. What would be the best way to go about doing this?
   Do I just create a thread for each request? Or should I use threadpool? I am new to threading so please try explain simply, also just a note there wont be more than 50 ServiceRequests running at once. I'm not sure if that could play a role in which way to implement it.
2. My concern is the call back function, Now once I have threaded each `RequestService` do I need to do anything to the callback function as it will be called from several different threads at any given time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 4 options

1. Use [`System.Threading's Thread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
   This is probably the worst option, since it doesn't take advantage of the *ThreadPool*. And since you are spinning up a considerable amount of threads (each one has approx. 1Mb of overhead, because each one has its stack among other things)
2. Use [`ThreadPoll.QueueUserWorkItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
   This is better, since it takes advantage of the *ThreadPool*. However it is less flexible than other methods since it won't allow you to return anything from the callback
3. Use [Task.Factory.StartNew](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321439%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
   If for some reason you can't use async/await this is the way to go. It takes advantage of the *ThreadPool* and is very flexible in terms of how it is used. `StartNew<T>` returns `Task<T>` which you can hold to and when you need the result you can call 'task.Result' which will block the calling thread until the task finishes.
4. Use [`async/await`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx)
   This is the easiest and the most in vogue way of doing async these days, and rightly so. It is just syntactic sugar for (3).

To use async/await your method has to return `Task<T>`, in your case `Task<ResponseObject>`. By convention the method name end with Async and has the keyword async

In your example, you can change ServiceRequest's Start method so that it is async:

```
public async Task<ResponseObject> StartAsync()
{
  //make the request using await
  //for example return await caller.PerformRequestAsync
  //an important note here, if the method you need to call is not async, you can use await Task.Factory.StartNew<ResponseObject>(method that returns ResponseObject)

  return response; //response is an instance of ResponseObject
}
```

And then you can change StartServiceRequests and make sure it is called periodically (instead of doing it on start [this is just a suggestion]):

```
private async void StartServiceRequestsAsync()
{
  IEnumerable<Task<ResponseObject>> requests = new List<Task<ResponseObject>>();
  foreach (ServiceRequest s in ServiceCommuncators)
  {
     requests.Add(s.StartAsync()); //this is non-blocking
  }

  foreach(var executingRequest in requests)
  {
     ResponseObject response = await executingRequest;
     //do something with response
  }
}
```

This will take advantage of the *ThreadPool*, which will manage the number of threads currently executing and will manage the creation and disposing of existing threads. Sometimes it is important to know how new threads get added to the *ThreadPool*. A new thread won't necessarily be created immediately when you use Task.Factory.StartNew (or you use async/await).

There's a .5sec wait that checks if the *ThreadPool* doesn't change (meaning that all threads are doing work) then new threads are added (again, adding a thread has a significant cost).

But in your case you want to perform 50 parallel requests (which you know each will take time, i.e. more than .5sec) so you want all to start. You can change the minimum number of threads in the *ThreadPool*([SetMinThreads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.setminthreads%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) and set it to 50 (this doesn't mean that 50 threads will immediately be created in the *ThreadPool*, it just means there's .5sec no wait until the ThreadPool reaches 50 threads).

Here's an example:

```
int minWorker, minIOC;
// Get the current settings.
ThreadPool.GetMinThreads(out minWorker, out minIOC);
// Change the minimum number of worker threads to 50, but 
// keep the old setting for minimum asynchronous I/O  
// completion threads. 
if (ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(50, minIOC))
{
    // The minimum number of threads was set successfully.
}
else
{
    // The minimum number of threads was not changed.
}
```

Comment: @Zapnologica I'll add an example of how to use async await in your cas shortly

Comment: Thanks, I am thinking of going await asyn. Especial as I am using EF to save the response in the CallBack Fucntion

Comment: Thanks SO much for this,  So currently I am using the system.timer to invoke the event every x seconds. Should I not do this?

Comment: @Zapnologica What I would probably do is still use the timer, but in the timer's event handler perform all the requests asynchronously (it would look like `StartServiceRequestsAsync` in the answer).
By the way, I've just remembered that there's yet another way to use the ThreadPool. Through [async delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/22t547yb(v=vs.110).aspx). I don't recommend though, it is probably the hardest way to use the _ThreadPool_

Comment: Oh, so let me just see if I understand you correctly.  I should get my list of all the services then I should loop through it and create a timer for each service, But then in the timers do event I Will just make ONE ServiceRequestAsync().(rather than making an ServiceRequest with a timer inside it) This way I could also update information on a service while this application is running and I would then be able accept those changes while running. AK I on the right track here? What would be the benefit of this approach threading wise?

Comment: @Zapnologica That would work, but you could also just use one timer, and in that timer's event handler, perform all the requests asynchronously. What I meant before is that the timer's event handler would look like the code in `StartServiceRequestsAsync` from my response.

Comment: but then how would I have different poll intervals for each service?

Comment: @Zapnologica I didn't know that was a requirement, in that case, I'd say use as many timers as you need. The advantage of having each request running in a thread is that while the request is waiting for the response no resources are being used (the thread is blocked, and it's not the ui thread), and you can have many threads simultaneously in this state while the ui continues to be responsive

Comment: THanks for you input. The way I have gone is a timer for each service, but then then the request it makes is an async task,  Now my only worry is the callback function. If there are many timers calling the same callback function will this be safe?

Comment: @Zapnologica Only if they make changes to a shared variable(if so, put that variable under a lock), otherwise you have nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

First, you definitely don't want to to be manually creating threads for this.  So yes, you should be making use of the thread pool.  Depending upon what version of the .net framework you are targeting, you can make use of TPL (Task Parallel Library) to create Tasks to make your service calls.  These tasks execute code using threads from the threadpool (by default).  More info can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

If you use the TPL, rather than callbacks, you can use continuations, with are other tasks to be run after the code has executed.

Comment: Then making use of TPL is an option, or you can make use of the async await syntax.  But to do that, you would need create tasks still to execute your async code. A bit more info here. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: So the approach you are speakign of, I would go and generate all my tasks. Save all the tasks in a list. Then go and asyncrounously execute all the task?